# how to show lightning layout item based on logged in user's role

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a LWC component to show navigation links to different list views. In .html it is written as below.

```
    <lightning-layout-item size="12" class="slds-p-vertical_xx-small">
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" class="align-items-center">
                    <lightning-layout-item size="1">
                        <lightning-icon icon-name={url4Icon} size="small"></lightning-icon>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="11" class="slds-p-left_small">
                        <div onclick={openFourthUrl} style="cursor: pointer;">{url4Label}</div>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
```

Need to show different layout items based on logged in user's role so as to show different navigation links to different user. New to LWC. Wondering how to achieve this
I tried below in the JS to get the user details and keep a flag to populate it to true based on the role. getting error:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined]

```
     @track CreatorRoleVal;
areDetailsVisible=false;

// using wire service getting current user data
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: USER_ID, fields: ['User.Name', 'User.UserRole.Name'] })
userData({error, data}) {
    if(data) {
        window.console.log('data ====> '+JSON.stringify(data));

        let objCurrentData = data.fields;
        if(objCurrentData.UserRole.value != null)
        {
        this.CreatorRoleVal=objCurrentData.value.fields.Name.value;
        window.console.log('data ====> '+CreatorRoleVal);
        if(this.CreatorRoleVal==='Sales Lead')
        {
            this.areDetailsVisible=true;
        }
        }
        
    } 
    else if(error) {
        window.console.log('error ====> '+JSON.stringify(error))
    } 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The docs [describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_conditional) how to render elements conditionally.

Comment: @DavidReed i have updated more info. Can you have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is accessing fields incorrectly:

```
        let objCurrentData = data.fields;
        if(objCurrentData.UserRole.value != null)
        {
        this.CreatorRoleVal=objCurrentData.value.fields.Name.value;
```

The layout of the returned `Record` object from the UI API is described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record.htm). It looks like you probably meant to assign

```
    this.CreatorRoleVal=objCurrentData.UserRole.value.fields.Name.value;
```

to get a nested object value.